# El combobox no envia el codigo seleccionado

Tags: php, mysqli, select

Buenas noches yo se que NO me extrañaban, pero sigo atascada como camión en la arena.

Logros de esta semana: Ya me 'avivé' y puedo pasar no sólo una sino mis tres variables. Ya preparé toda la consulta 'bonita' como le gusta a Cedano, despues la cuelgo. Pero sigo teniendo un problemita. EL COMBOBOX no funciona **no envía el idgr que yo elijo** (ver ) Utilicé el mismo que uso en formularios de completar datos y que ahí funcionan estupendo para el INSERT, aquí no funciona para el UPDATE ¿magia, hechicería, simple ignorancia mía? Va código

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
// Include config file
require_once '990conn.php';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<link href="css/sbg.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
require_once '990conn.php';
$idusr=$_GET['idusr'];
$nomb=$_GET['nomb'];    
$grup=$_GET['grup'];
echo "<p>Nº usuar: <strong>$idusr</strong>";
echo "<p>Nombre : <strong>$nomb</strong>";
echo "<p>Grupo act: <strong>$grup</strong>";
?>  
<table width="280" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" target="_self" class="row" title="f098">
<!-- Selecciono el grupo dinamicamente de la tabla $t98g = 98gr que solo contiene dos columnas idgr (numérica) y gr (nombre del grupo) ver foto-->
<tr><td>
<select name="gru" size="12" required id="gru" form="f098" title="gru" >
    <option value=""></option>
<?php $sql098b="select idgr, gr from $t98g"; 
$r098b=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql098b); 
while($rw098b=mysqli_fetch_array($r098b))
{ 
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rw098b['idgr']; ?>"><?php echo $rw098b['gr']; ?></option>
<?php 
    $gru=$rw098b['idgr'];
} 
?>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><input name="bt-098" type="submit" class="btn-primary" id="bt-098" value="CAMBIAR GRUPO" /> </tr>
<tr><input name="idusr" value="<?php echo $idusr; ?>"></tr><!--EL idusr sigue firme-->
<!--<tr><input value="<?php //echo $gru; ?>"/></tr><!--AQUI ESTA MAL, toma por defecto el último de la lista 8=licencia-->
</form></tbody></table>
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
if(isset($_POST['bt-098']))
{
    $sql098 = "UPDATE 98usr SET 98grupo=$gru WHERE 98idusr=$idusr";
        if(mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql098)){
    echo "El grupo fue cambiado."; // me dice siempre que fue cambiado
} else{
    echo "ERROR: No es posible ejecutar $sql098. " . $mysqli->error;
}
}
}
// Close connection
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Va foto [image: Gente muy enferma todos terminan con licencia]

Comment: A qué te refieres con que no lo envía?

Comment: En realidad sí envía pero siempre el último de la lista, en este caso el 8, y todos los empleados terminan sin poder ingresar porque están de licencia.

Comment: Estás recogiendo el valor del input no del select, el <select name="gru" > "gru" es lo que debes recoger

Comment: Hola @LuisFernando anule el renglon, pero si te fijas tanto el select como el update se refieren únicamente al $gru. Sigue con lo mismo toma el último valor de la lista.

Comment: Hola, ya me fijé que el $gru lo estás tomando de la base de datos, no del select. Por eso te coloca el último. Déjame llegar a casa para probar desde mi máquina porque ahora mismo estoy en el móvil.

Comment: También veo que estas mezclando *Estilo por procedimientos* con *Estilo orientado a objetos*, es decir, en tu `select`usas `mysqli_query` y en tu `update` veo `$mysqli->query`, no es aconsejable. Has probado cambiar como te ha mencionado @Luis `$gru=$rw098b['idgr'];` por `$gru = $_POST['gru'];`?

Comment: Hola @Bulten, si lo había probado antes y lo volví a hacer ahora a tu instancia, el resultado es  Notice: Undefined index: grup in C:\wamp64\www\wip\098usredit-00.php on line 19
Que es precisamente la línea que se cambia. la idea de utilizar como definición de $gru el row 'idgr' es que ese sería en 'número' que debiera tomar al elegir de la lista de la foto

Comment: Por otro lado todos mis códigos son un poquito caóticos, pero siempre pasibles de ser corregidos, gracias por la idea. ya intento unificarlos al menos

Comment: El **Notice: Undefined index** es porque debes resetear siempre tus *variables* con las que vas a trabajar, en tu caso veo dos en tu sentencia `update` (`$gru` y `$idusr`), si pensamos por lógico son obtenido por `POST`, entonces al principio de tu programa reseteas tus variables, algo como: `$gru = $idusr = NULL;`. Ya que en ocasiones habra un `echo $gru;` sin que dicha variable existe, en dicho caso te mandara el *Notice*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un consejo es no mezclar el *estilos orientado a objetos* con el *estilo por procedimientos* en tus sentencias. Si te fijas en el [manual de PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) la conexión cambia de un estilo a otro.

Segundo punto en tu sentencia `update` no veo que le estas pasando los valores de tu formulario obtenido por `POST` en las comprobaciones, sino lo obtienes desde tu `select`.

**Un posible ejemplo (Estilo orientado a objetos)**

*conexión*

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("servidor", "usuario", "contraseña", "base de datos");

/* comprobar la conexión */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

*formulario*

```
<?php
  require_once '990conn.php';
  $idusr=$_GET['idusr'];
  $nomb=$_GET['nomb'];    
  $grup=$_GET['grup'];
  //vienen de página anterior.
  echo"
    <p>Nº usuar: <strong>$idusr</strong></p>
    <p>Nombre: <strong>$nomb</strong></p>
    <p>Grupo act: <strong>$grup</strong></p>
  ";
?>  

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" class="row" title="f098">
    <select name="gru" size="11" id="gru" form="f098" required >
        <option value="0"></option>
        <?php
            //Sentencia select
            $sql098b="select idgr, gr from $t98g"; 
            $r098b= $mysqli->query($sql098b);
            //Salida datos
            while($row = $r098b->fetch_assoc()) { 
        ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['idgr']; ?>"><?php echo $row['gr']; ?></option>
        <?php     
            } 
            //Cerrar sentencia.
            $r098b->close();
        ?>
    </select>   
    <input type="hidden" name="idusr" value="<?php echo $idusr; ?>" /><!--EL idusr sigue firme-->
    <input name="bt-098" type="submit" class="btn-primary" id="bt-098" value="CAMBIAR GRUPO" />
</form>

<?php
    //Reseteo
    $gru_frm = $idusr_frm = NULL;

    //Si esta definido el formulario y no es NULL.
    if (isset($_POST['bt-098'])) {
        //Comprobación si el select esta vacío.
        if (empty($_POST['gru'][0])) {
            echo "Selecciona el grupo dinamicamente.";
        } elseif (empty($_POST['idusr'])) {
            echo "Hubbo un error con el 'ID'.";
        } else {
            //Obtienes datos formulario
            $gru_frm = $_POST['gru'];
            //Como tambien tienes un $idusr que viene de otra página, e puesto idusr_frm para no tener conflictos y saber que viene desde el formulario.
            $idusr_frm = $_POST['idusr'];
        }
        //Verdadero datos formulario.
        if ($gru_frm && $idusr_frm) {
            //Sentencia update
            $sql098 = $mysqli->query("UPDATE 98usr SET 98grupo=$gru_frm WHERE 98idusr=$idusr_frm");
            //Comprobamos si se ejecuto.
            if($sql098===true) {
                echo "El grupo fue cambiado."; // me dice siempre que fue cambiado
            } else{
                echo "ERROR: No es posible ejecutar $sql098. " . $mysqli->error;
            }
            //Cerrar sentencia.
            $sql098->close();
        }           
    }   
?>
```

> **Nota:** te aconsejo a usar [`sentencia preparadas`](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) para obtener un mayor seguridad en tu aplicación, aqui te dejo un post interesante ([¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)).

Comment: Hice una unificacion de 'lenguajes' y lo pegué en mi código original, veo que hay mucho para analizar en tu código @D.Bulten y es hora de hacer noni (ya cené y no fue con gaseosa), no te enojes en cuanto me levante, lo analizo lo pruebo y te cuento. Muchísimas gracias por el interés y tus respuestas. Talueguito! Buena noche para vos

Comment: Buen día @D.Bulten, Probé tu código tal cual y tengo algunas dudas y algún problema: 1) No cambia el grupo lo deja como está 2) al responder lo hace con "Selecciona el grupo dinamicamente." por lo que temo que no sigue el resto de la rutina 3) El idusr que debe utilizarse es el que viene de la página anterior por lo que no debiera ser considerado null, ya que no vuelve a ingresarse manualmente como si debiera ocurrir con el valor del grupo a traves del select. Voy a hacer algunos cambios como los que te comento a ver si funciona. Te tengo al tanto, a menos que se te ocurra algo mejor. GRACIAS

Comment: @SilviaGaviotaGarcia no sé si el primer punto podría fallar, porque estas pasando el *ID* del grupo y no su *Nombre*. ¿En tu `<select>` del formulario estas obteniendo correctamente los valores en tu `options` a elegir?  Luego el `$idusr_frm` lo reseteo en `NULL` al principio del programa. Pero si te fijas bien en el formulario hay un `<input type="hidden" name="idusr" value="<?php echo $idusr; ?>" />` es decir, el *id* obtenido por `GET` también se pasa mediante el formulario independientemente para mantener su relación en el `update`, no lo he probado, pero a simple visto no veo un error.

Comment: Hola le metí 'gancho' a todo y no cambia ni siquiera a licencia. como antes. Pregunto no convendría verificar los valores antes de pasarlos Como un que muestre los dos datos el idusr y el idgrupo=idgr o como me ocurre en la página anterior al pasar sobre el lápiz, ahí yo se que variables estoy entregando y con que valor, Ej:           echo "<td align='center'><a href='098usredit-000.php?idusr=$idusr&nomb=$nomb&grup=$grup' target= _self ><img src='img/001-lapiz2.png' width='16' height='16' alt=''/></a></td>";
Espero se me entienda!!!

Comment: @SilviaGaviotaGarcia ¿Si al principio haces un `var_dump($_POST);` que valores obtienes? Luego en tu formulario estas visualizando correctamentos a los grupos en tu `<select>`?

Comment: la tabla $t98g sólo tiene dos campos los que se ven en la foto  y forman parte de mi select: idgr y gr  (el primero es numerico y es segundo el nombre (orientador, licencia etc).
La otra tabla $t98=98usr tiene varios campos pero solo utilizo en este caso el 98idusr, 98nomb y 98grupo (que es el número que se debiera actualizar con el idgr del select.
Al hacer el var_dump justo debajo de donde toma las variables de la pagina anterior me contesta: C:\wamp64\www\wip\098usredit-000.php:26:
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Si lo pongo en el último renglon  antes de cerrar el php dice:
C:\wamp64\www\wip\098usredit-000.php:80:
array (size=2)
  'idusr' => string '31' (length=2)
  'bt-098' => string 'CAMBIAR GRUPO' (length=13)
O sea está el usuario pero no esta el grupo o no lo tomo!

Comment: @SilviaGaviotaGarcia otro pequeño fallo que vi, ya que la función `var_dump` no te manda datos, en tu `action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` no has lanzado el `echo`, en mi respuesta está igual, ahora la modifico también, pero cambia dicha línea por `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"`

Comment: Con  esta última modificación al principio aparecen las tres variables, elijo el grupo y no solo no actualiza el grupo sino que ahora lo único que reconoce es el idusr lo demás se puso en blanco (pobre ya no tiene ni nombre ni grupo)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68413/discussion-between-d-bulten-and-silvia-gaviota-garcia).